# Nuxt 3 auth token in localStorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

I try create login in my app. I have login response, which return access_token and add this in localStorage. My code in pinia

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { axiosInstance } from '@/axios.config'


export const useAuth = defineStore('auth',{
    state: ()=>({
        user:[],
        access_token:[],
    }),

    actions:{
        async loginUser(email:string, password:string){
            try{
                const res = await axiosInstance.post('/login',{email, password,  withCredentials: true,})
                this.user = await res.data.user
                this.access_token = await res.data.access_token
                localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data.access_token)
               await useRouter().push('/')
              
             }catch(e){
            console.log(e.response.data)
        }
    },
```

and axios config:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const API_URL = 'https://quiz.bojarm.pl/api';

export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':  'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin',
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`,
    },
})
```

When I try login token work good, but when I reload page the access_token doesn't work and logout user

Answer (score 0):

**Axios** and **@nuxtjs/axios** is not recommended to use with Nuxt 3

Use **useFetch()** - it should solve your problem.

Read about it here:
https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching/#usefetch

Answer (score 0):

Pinia storage is not persisted. Use local storage to store the data you need to persist.

[Checkout this link](https://nuxt.com/modules/storage)